# PHP mime exact definition

Tags: php

Can someone please define what 'mime' exactly is in php? I have researched all over and have found people using it but I can't find it defined anywhere. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIME stands for "Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions. It's a way of identifying files on the Internet according to their nature and format. For example, using the "Content-type" header value defined in a HTTP response, the browser can open the file with the proper extension/plugin.

for more information visit:http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html